# How do add a toolbar on the browser example of PySide?

Tags: python, url, browser, toolbar, pyside

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from PySide.QtHelp import *
from PySide.QtNetwork import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://google.com"))
web.show()
web.resize(650, 750)
q_pixmap = QPixmap('icon.ico')
q_icon = QIcon(q_pixmap)
QApplication.setWindowIcon(q_icon)
web.setWindowTitle('Browser')
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do  I add a toolbar on this with two buttons:
One called 'URL 1' and the other 'URL 2' So if they click on it it will open a url. YOu could compare this with a list with favorite websites if you know what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: Well not really I did succeed to make a toolbar. But I want that a button in the toolbar will reload a other page in the same window. So that it will redirect to other website. How do I do that?

Comment: I updated the answer. Check it out now. You just have to load another URL into the web browser in the callback function that you connected with the `QAction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good [PyQt Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/) to start with.

To get a toolbar you have to create a MainWindow which will have a toolbar and contain your browser window as your central widget. To add items to the toolbar you first have to create actions and then add those actions to the toolbar. Actions can be connected with a function that will be executed when the action is triggered.

Here is a working snippet:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # Create an exit action
        exitAction = QtGui.QAction('Load Yahoo', self)
        # Optionally you can assign an icon to the action
        # exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q') # set the shortcut
        # Connect the action with a custom function
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.load_yahoo)
        # Create the toolbar and add the action
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        # Setup the size and title of the main window
        self.resize(650, 750)
        self.setWindowTitle('Browser')

        # Create the web widget and set it as the central widget.
        self.web = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)
        self.web.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://google.com'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.web)

    def load_yahoo(self):
        self.web.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://yahoo.com'))


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()    
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```